# Simple numerical test that a function looks like sin(x) or ((tanh(x) + 1) / 2)

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, ode

I solve some very large systems of ODEs (somewhere in the range of 2,000 to 10,000 variables) and I need to make quick decisions about the output. Let's call the evolution variable `t` and a vector of solution variables as `x`. The solutions can look like:

1. `a * exp(-b * t)`, where `a << 1` and `b > 0`. This is not interesting. So, it starts at some small value(s) and basically decay(s) to 0. This one is easy to spot.
2. `c * ((tanh(b * t) + 1) / 2)`, where `-1 < c < 1` and `b > 0`. So, it starts at around 0 and then evolves into something between `-1` and `+1`.
3. Something, which looks like a very skewed `c * sin(b(t) * t)`, where `-1 < c < 1` and `b(t)` is a manifestation of the fact that the solution is non-linear.

Let’s say that I sample around 1,000 (or any other number) of some aggregate results on the way and I need to distinguish between 2 and 3. After all, it is obvious when you look at the chart!

However, it is often the case that the solution may stay around zero for a good while and then starts to deviate into #2 or #3 after a while. So, whatever happens later in “time” should have more weight than whatever happens at the beginning. So, basically, I need a number or two to “tell” that a solution is `tanh`-like or `sin`-like and, obviously, there might be something in between!

What would be the appropriate algorithm for that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are many ways to quantify 'error' in curve-fitting, depending on what is needed. For example, calculate and compare the absolute area (rect / trapezoidal) above and below the ideal curves at the sample points. You could start with, for example, 10 sample points, and progressively use more if you don't get a clear answer. I'm assuming you can pre-calculate the real curve values at the sample (t) values.

Comment: Also, `c.(tanh(b.t) + 1)/2` has `y = c` as an asymptote for `t > 0`. For a given (t), the distance to the aymptote is: `c/(exp(2.b.t) + 1)` (double check!). So a function that evolves to look like (2) should become increasingly 'flat', after the initial transients have decayed.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated, as it's not about programming, per se. In fact, it's probably a better fit for [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would try [correlation coefficient](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/correlation.htm) sadly looks that old link is not working anymore try [this one](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-formula) instead